# Take your OS away on USB stick?

Tags: usb, software-recommendation, live-usb

I went back to Ubuntu after longer time, my Vaio is running 14.04 last 10 days 
and I'm really happy with it..Systemback works wonders xD

I'm wondering if there is a way to run/sync your OS to USB drive and take it on the way and use it as "live disk" on other machines?

When you plug it back to your "main" rig it just syncs the data and software and you're back up to date.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a way to atleast partialy do the intended "takeaway".

Systemback is a Windows Restore like app and can make live copy of my system to USB stick so I can use it on other computers.

So when I come back from my trip where i cant/don't/need to take my hardware 
I can just flash the LiveUSB to my notebook and I'm back up to date.

Also, Systemback is a great Ubuntu repair tool. It saved me hours or reinstalling and "sudo dat sudo that" last 24h. From the point you have a perfect Ubuntu running, back it up, it takes 2min and you are safe ;)